# limit of $\sqrt{x^6}$ as $x$ approaches $-\infty$

Tags: limits

I need to solve this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to - \infty}{\frac {\sqrt{9x^6-5x}}{x^3-2x^2+1}}$$

The answer is $-3$, but I got 3 instead. This is my process:

$$\lim_{x \to - \infty}{\frac {\sqrt{9x^6-5x}}{x^3-2x^2+1}} =
\lim_{x \to - \infty}{\frac {\sqrt{x^6(9-\frac {5}{x^2})}}{x^3(1-\frac {2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})}} =
\lim_{x \to - \infty}{\frac {\sqrt{x^6}\sqrt{(9-\frac {5}{x^2})}}{x^3(1-\frac {2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})}} =
\lim_{x \to - \infty}{\frac {\require{cancel} \cancel{x^3} \sqrt{(9-\frac {5}{x^2})}}{\require{cancel} \cancel{x^3}(1-\frac {2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3})}} =
\frac {3}{1} = +3$$

I've been told that in the third step the $\sqrt{x^6}$ should be equal $\textbf{-}\sqrt{x^3}$, but I didn't understand why.

I'll be glad to get your help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been told that in the third step the $\sqrt{x^6}$ should be equal $\textbf{-}\sqrt{x^3}$, but I didn't understand why.

Because $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ is only true if $a \ge 0$; for $a \le 0$, you have $\sqrt{a^2}=-a$.

You can summarize this as follows (and remember by heart!), for all $a$ you have:
$$\boxed{\sqrt{a^2}=|a|}$$
Apply this to $a=x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that $\sqrt{x^6}=|x^3|$ and $\frac{|x^3|}{x^3}=-1$ when $x$ is negative

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $y < 0$ then $$\sqrt{y^2} = |y| = -y.$$
Take $y=-3$ for example. In your case, $y = x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

To check or avoid confusion with sign let $y=-x \to \infty$ then

$$\lim_{x \to - \infty}{\frac {\sqrt{9x^6-5x}}{x^3-2x^2+1}}=\lim_{y \to \infty}{\frac {\sqrt{9y^6+5y}}{-y^3-2y^2+1}}=-3$$